# WPF LifeCyle in an Add-in

Tags: wpf, vsto, state, dispatcher, class-library

I've created an add-in, which call via Reflection, a WPF Class Library.
Since this is a class library, I had to instanciate manually a `new System.Windows.Application()`.

Then, the class constructor (the one called via reflection) create a window, and Show() (with Dispatcher.Run() to avoid the window to close immediately) or ShowDialog().

Since my application is into an add-in, Application is still alive.
Therefore, I can instanciate this only once.

On the first launch (when Application is instanciated), the Application.Current.Dispatcher is Running.

But on the second launch, I firured out that the Application.Current.Dispatcher was Stopped.
I never call InvokeShutdown() so I don't understand when the Dispatcher is stopped.

When I launch this a second time, Application is already instanciated (it's normal) but Dispatcher stopped.

Any idea ?
Thanks !

**Edit :** In my Add-in, I've tried 2 ways :

*First way :*

```
        foreach (Type type in ass2_l.GetTypes())
        {
            if (type.Name == "Loader")
            {
                object obj_l = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                BindingFlags bf_l = BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
                object[] argList_l = new object[1];
                argList_l[0] = "ok";
                type.InvokeMember("Load", bf_l, null, obj_l, argList_l);
            }
        }
```

When I call directly the dll from the add-in, Application.Current.Dispatcher is in Background State, with name "VSTA_Main".
When I launch a second time, Dispatcher is still in background state.

*Second way :*

```
        t_m = new Thread(loadDll);
        t_m.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t_m.Start();
```

loadDll actually contain the same code of the "first way" code.
When I launch this part for the first time, the Dispatcher is Running, and all is perfectly normal.
When launched the second time, Dispatcher is stopped.

**EDIT 2 :** 
The problem is in the second way.
When loadDll is finished and then I click again on my add-in button, t_m is stopped and creating another one don't resolve the problem since the Dispatcher ManagedThreadId has the old t_m ManagerThreadId :/

**EDIT 3 :**
The problem is definately not caused by the Add-in.
If you Just create a program that launch a thread everytime you click on a button.
The thread try to instanciate a DLL WPF Class Library (by reflection), and if you click a second time on this button (calling another thread), as the Dispatcher is still "linked" to the old thread, the Dispatcher is "stopped" (like the old thread)

Comment: Is App.ShutdownMode set to explicit, or on last window close?

Comment: I've tried both. 
But I think I've found where the problem is exactly.

In my Add-in, I launch a STA thread when I click on a button (created by my add-in).
This thread call the WPF class by Reflection.

I tried to call twice the library in the same thread, and Dispatcher is still running.
It means that the problem is the end of the calling thread, causing the Dispatcher to stop... but why ? I don't know :/

Comment: Can you provide a short code sample that repros the problem?  Also, not sure if it applies, but `Application` doesn't like to have multiple instances per `AppDomain`...

Comment: I've edited my code. BTW, I don't have multiple instances per AppDomain since everytime I want to instanciate a new Application, I check if Application.Current is null before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem using an infinite loop to stay the thread in running state, with AutoResetEvent / ManualResetEvent to start/stop the thread...

As the thread never finish (and call a method which load the WPF UI dll when he receive the start event), we never stop the thread (until we stop the Add-in), and the dispatcher is never stopped too.

BTW, thank you for all your answers :)

Comment: Can you add the code sample to your answer? I face the same issue , however the dispatcher does not shut down in some machines and it does in some machines.

Answer (score 7):

In ThisAddin.Startup event handler put this code:

```
private void ThisAddInStartup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (System.Windows.Application.Current == null)
        new System.Windows.Application();
    System.Windows.Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown
}
```

That should sort it out, it has worked fine for me in the past..

Comment: Unfortunately, not solving my problem since putting this code makes my Dispatcher always "background".

But the problem is not an add-in problem. Indeed, if you try a Console Application, launching a new Thread (at least 2 times), and in this thread, calling a new wpf class library (which create a new Application), the Dispatcher is Stopped in the second time launched thread :/

Comment: My knowledge of the internals of the Application class is a little fuzzy, but I assume because it is related to WPF it has it's own message pump and other UI Thread related things in a typical application.

VSTO runs in a STA, and I assume that whatever thread you say new Application() starts running the message pump, when that thread terminates, so does the message pump running on that thread. Instantiating on a background thread wouldn't be a good thing, and as I said the above has worked for me.

Could you please post the sample code, I would be interested in digging deeper into this one.

Comment: Also, the above code creates the application within the VSTO Startup method, which is basically the add-ins UI thread, running within the Office STA (I think..). You should then be creating the windows on that UI thread, whether you use a Dispatcher or a SynchronisationContext to do it, it shouldn't matter. But you should have ALL WPF related code executing on the same UI thread that the Application class was created on.